# Is exporting developer profiles still necessary when building on different machines?

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode8

I was under the impression in WWDC16 it was anounced that exporting developer profiles from one machine to another was no longer neccesary and XCode (8.n)managed everything now.
However, in the Apple documentation here https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/MaintainingCertificates/MaintainingCertificates.html it states:

> If you want to code sign your app using another Mac, you export your
>   developer profile on the Mac you used to create your certificates and
>   import it on the other Mac.

Is this correct, or out of date documentation?

In addition the documentation also states:

> (talking about the signing identity) "If the private key is lost,
>   you'll have to create an entirely new identify to sign code"

But if it is the case that exporting developer profiles is no longer necessary anymore, then this must be incorrect too? Otherwise, how could the same account build on more than one mac without there being a private key on each (put there automatically by XCode), and if a private key on one mac gets deleted its ok as its on the other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is out of date. Xcode 8 will generate a new identity for you on another Mac.